# Alluvial Plots internal company movement

Tags: r

I have some data which I would like to convert to an alluvial plot. I would like it to show from which department people move into, and which they move out to. So three axis the first being where they come from, the second being where they are going to/leaving from and the third being where they moved to. I have this data:

```
set.seed(1)
df<-tibble(c("Moved in", "Moved in", "Moved in", "Moved in", "Moved out", "Moved out", "Moved out", "Moved out", "Moved out"),
       c("Functions", "Functions", "Functions", "Functions", "Functions", "Functions", "Functions", "Functions", "Functions"),
       c("From Functions", "From Sales", "From Supply", "From Commercial","To Group", "To Products", "Sales", "To Supply", "To Commercial"),
       c(rpois(9, 5)),
       .name_repair = ~c("move","area","action_reason","Freq"))
```

The plot that i get is just "flat" and does not connect to the different departments...

Comment: Please post what you tried

Comment: Please also post the plot you get.